# How to find duplicates value on gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a gridview data and want to highlight the duplicates values. I want to change all the duplicates value color become red.

gridview data:

```
 ID |  Items     |
 1  |  Item1     |  --> this will be red
 2  |  Item2     |        
 1  |  Item1     |  --> this will be red
 1  |  Item1     | --> this will be red


 Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As GridView, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim idxPrev As Integer = e.Row.RowIndex - 1
        If 1 <= e.Row.RowIndex Then
            If e.Row.Cells(3).Text = sender.Rows(idxPrev).Cells(3).Text Then
                e.Row.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
                sender.Rows(idxPrev).ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

my code only able to change a certain data, because I set the idxPrev only for the previous one, so it only change able to detect the previous index. I want it to check and change all of the gridview duplicates data. is it possible to do that? would you mind to help me to solve this problem?

Thanks in advances....

Comment: Try checking each row in a foreach loop in GridView_RowDataBound event

Comment: Before binding to  datasource to the gridview, Save a list of records that has duplicates into a collection. During the GridView_RowDataBound event for each item, check the value against the saved list. If exist, paint it red.

Comment: @Ullas I've already try adding for each row on the above code... But it doesn't change anything...

Comment: @ajakblackgoat thanks for the suggestion... Can you help me how to save the duplicate into a collection? What should I do to make it like that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this please.
**SOURCE**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#3AC0F2" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" ItemStyle-Width="30" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Items" HeaderText="Items" ItemStyle-Width="150" />/>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**CODE BEHIND**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bind();
}
protected void bind()
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from tblSample";
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    HighlightDuplicate(this.GridView1);
    con.Close();
}
public void HighlightDuplicate(GridView gridview)
{
    for (int currentRow = 0; currentRow < gridview.Rows.Count - 1; currentRow++)
    {
        GridViewRow rowToCompare = gridview.Rows[currentRow];
        for (int otherRow = currentRow + 1; otherRow < gridview.Rows.Count; otherRow++)
        {
            GridViewRow row = gridview.Rows[otherRow];
            bool duplicateRow = true;
            if (int.Parse(rowToCompare.Cells[0].Text) != int.Parse(row.Cells[0].Text))
            {
                duplicateRow = false;
            }
            else if (duplicateRow)
            {
                rowToCompare.BackColor = Color.Red;
                row.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Add the following namespaces too in the code behind page.

```
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
```

Comment: Thanks Ullas.... But it's still doesn't work... Thank you for helping me... I really appreciate the though...

Comment: What is your issue? I tested this code, this is working fine from my side.

Answer (score 0):

```
   /*highlight duplicate row in gridview */
 public void HighlightDuplicate(GridView GridView1)
        {
            for (int ThisRow = 0; ThisRow < GridView1.Rows.Count - 1; ThisRow++)
            {
                Label lbl_cd = (Label)GridView1.Rows[ThisRow].FindControl("lblcd");
                lblhidcd.Value = lbl_EmpCode.Text;
                GridViewRow CompareRow =`enter code here` GridView1.Rows[ThisRow];
                for (int NextRow = ThisRow + 1; NextRow < GridView1.Rows.Count; NextRow++)
                {
                    GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[NextRow];
                    bool DuplicateRow = true;
                    Label lbl_cd1= (Label)GridView1.Rows[NextRow].FindControl("lblcd");
                    hidnxtrowhidcd.Value = lbl_cd1= .Text;
                    if ((lblhidcd.Value) == (hidnxtrowhidcd.Value ))
                    {
                        row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.BlanchedAlmond;
                        CompareRow.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.BlanchedAlmond;
                    }
                    else if (DuplicateRow)
                    {
                        DuplicateRow = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please don't just post code without explanation - describe how it solves the problem too.